# Question on holomorphic map from compact Riemann surfaces into projective space associated with base point free divisor

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, riemann-surfaces, projective-space

I am reading through Rick Miranda's Algebraic Curves and Riemann Surfaces. There is a proposition that is left as an exercise for the readers to check. However, I am not sure how to verify it.

$\textbf{Set up:}$ In the following, $X$ is a compact Riemann surface. $D$ is a base point free divisor, i.e. for any $p\in X$, there is some divisor $E'$ in the complete linear system $|D|=\{E:E\sim D,\, E\geq 0\}$ so that $E'(p)=0$. It was shown in the text that any such divisor $D$ gives rise to a holomorphic map $\phi_D:X\to\mathbb P^n$, by choosing any basis $\{f_0,\dots,f_n\}\subset L(D)$ and take $\phi_D=[f_0:f_1:\cdots:f_n]$. Picking another basis would only affect $\phi_D$ up to a linear change of coordinates. We have also seen that there is a natural identification $|D|\cong \mathbb P(L(D))$; and $L(D-p)$ is a hyperplane in $L(D)$ when $D$ is base point free.

$\textbf{Proposition:}$ The projectivization $\mathbb P(L(D-p))$ corresponds to the subspace $\{E:E\sim D,\,E\geq p\}\subset |D|$. The map $\phi:X\to |D|^*$ defined by $p\mapsto \{E:E\sim D,\,E\geq p\}$, with a suitable coordinates, is the map $\phi_D$, here $|D|^*$ is the dual projective space.

$\textbf{My thoughts:}$ I don't know how should I identify $\mathbb P^n$ with $|D|^*$. So I tried to fix a point $p\in X$ first, choose a basis $\{f_1,\dots,f_n\}$ of $L(D-p)$, and complete it to a basis $\{f_0,\dots,f_n\}$ of $L(D)$. Then $\phi_D(p)=[f_0(p):\dots:f_n(p)]=[1:0:\cdots:0]$ since $\operatorname{div}(f_0)(p)$ is smaller than that of other $f_i$'s. So I figured maybe the point $[1:0:\cdots:0]$ should be identified with $\{E:E\sim D,\,E\geq p\}$. However if I choose another point $q$, then $\phi_D$ would adjust linearly. It is not so clear to me how $\phi_D$ would change.

I would like to be given hints on how to prove this proposition. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hyperplanes in any vector space are parametrized by the space $\mathbb P(V^*)$. The correspondence sends a linear functional $\phi$ that cuts out the hyperplane to the line $\phi$ spans in $V^*$ (multiplying $\phi$ by a nonzero constant does not change the hyperplane). You have shown that $L(D-p)$ is a hyperplane in $L(D)$, so you get a map $p \mapsto [L(D-p)] \in \mathbb P(L(D)^*) \cong |D|^*$. So it remains to check that this map agrees with $\phi_D$ for some fixed choice of basis of $L(D)$ (and, if you really want, check what happens after you change the basis).

Comment: @JaneDoé Sorry I didn't make my question clear in the post. I understood the first part of the proposition. My confusion is that I don't know how to relate $[L(D-p)]$ for different points $p$. For example, it seems to me that I should write down an isomorphism between $\mathbb P^n$ and $|D|^*$ in order to check that $\phi$ and $\phi_D$ are the same map. But I do not know how to construct such an isomorphism. (I am not even sure if this is the right way.)

Comment: Well, the isomorphism is: choose a basis of $L(D)$. This gives isomorphisms $L(D) \cong \mathbb C^{n+1}$, $L(D)^* \cong (\mathbb C^{n+1})^* \cong \mathbb C^{n+1}$ and $|D|^* \cong \mathbb P(L(D)^*) \cong \mathbb P(\mathbb C^{n+1}) = \mathbb P^n$